# Add a Panel to Datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview, panel

I want to put Panel into column which contains a group of controls into datagridview.
How could I do that? Because the standard methods allow to add checkbox, button, combobox and few more, but I can't find how to put simple Panel.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panel control is also inherited from control class so you can add it like any other control

Below is the code i used in one of my projects .

```
private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("name");
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add("");
    }
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 200;

    /*
     * First method : Convert to an existed cell type such ComboBox cell,etc
     */

    DataGridViewComboBoxCell ComboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
    ComboBoxCell.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "aaa","bbb","ccc" });
    this.dataGridView1[0, 0] = ComboBoxCell;
    this.dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = "bbb";

    DataGridViewTextBoxCell TextBoxCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    this.dataGridView1[0, 1] = TextBoxCell;
    this.dataGridView1[0, 1].Value = "some text";

    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell CheckBoxCell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
    CheckBoxCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    this.dataGridView1[0, 2] = CheckBoxCell;
    this.dataGridView1[0, 2].Value = true;

    /*
     * Second method : Add control to the host in the cell
     */
    DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();
    dtp.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
    //add DateTimePicker into the control collection of the DataGridView
    this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(dtp);
    //set its location and size to fit the cell
    dtp.Location = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 3,true).Location;
    dtp.Size = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 3,true).Size;
}
```