# Using a custom UserControl as a Column in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, user-controls

I've created a custom User Control that inherits from UserControl. It is pretty basic, it has some text fields, drop downs, and some radio buttons for right now. Ultimately I would like to string together 100's of these side by side to allow the user to fill out as many as they would like. The ideal solution to this would be to have a DataGridView where each column is an instance of my custom User Control. Is there a way to accomplish this? Or perhaps a better/alternative solution?

My initial thought is I'll need to create a custom DataGridViewCell that uses this custom control, but I don't know if this is a) possible and b) the most efficient way to do this.

I'm working with winforms.

Comment: Consider placing a few of these UserControls in a FlowLayoutPanel. If the user needs to fill out more, have a button that will add more UserControls.

Comment: Hey :)

Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055737/add-a-panel-to-datagridview

Comment: You can create a custom column which hosts a composite control in cell while editing. But instead of creating such grid column, you can use a button column and edit values in a window which you open above grid. Also you can use `TableLayoutPanel` container to have a grid-like user interface.

Comment: You need to understand that any cell but the current one is really just a couple of pixels. Only the current cell displays some sort of editing control. If you only need one column going for a FLP is a good design for a few hundred items. For thousands it will not work so well and going back to a DGV, that host one UC in the editing cell may work better, provided you paint all other cells to show all your fields.. - If you want to go all the way [here is the MSDN how to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the topic, but you __could__ cheat ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a `UserControl` as a Column in a `DataGridView`. To display scores/rows/columns of your `UserControl` (`'yuc'`) there are several options. Here are three that come to my mind:

- Drop the DGV and go for a `FlowLayoutPanel`. This is simple to implement and will work pretty much out of the box. The only con is that the performance will get sluggish if you have too many controls in total in it. Let's assume your UC (`yuc`) has 10 controls; a few thousand controls are the limit in WinForms, so a few (100-300) `yucs` will work ok, but beyond that you need to rethink the design.
- Go all the way and create a specialized `DataGridView` Cell that will host your `yuc`. Here is a [complete and nice walk-through](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). As you can see this will amount to quite a lot of extra work; classes to add, interfaces to implement etc.. And, what is worse: All this is really meant to make the new cell type **act like a regular DGV cell**, read it will hold and allow you to edit **only one** value. That's a lot less than what your `yuc` probably can do..
- Option 3: Cheat! You can combine the avantages of `yuc` data and `DGV` display performance if you display only **one** `yuc` in the **current** cell by **overlaying** it and make all other cells display what their `yucs` would look like.

This third option will allow you to add pretty much as many rows as your memory allows, although it is worth mentioning that the total column widths can't exceed 64k.

I can think of two ways to create the right display: The cells could display a `Bitmap` they hold along with their other data in a `Tag` structure or they could paint them in the `CellPaint` event. The former takes more memory but should work faster.

You need to create a **data class** `yucData` for your `yuc` that holds all data needed to initalze a `yuc`. It could also hold a `Bitmap` a `yuc` can create using the `DrawToBitmap` method.

Now each time the current cell is moved you show/move the editing `yuc` and initialize it to the data in the cell's `Tag`. When the values have changed you update the `Bitmap`.

And in the `CellPainting` event you draw the `Bitmap` into each cell.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005397/accordion-in-windows-forms-datagridview/29006361?s=3|0.1695#29006361) for an example of overlaying a `UserControl` onto a `DataGridView`. There it overlays a whole row, which grows accordion-like to hold all its size.. The other rows and cells are quite regular..

What I wrote is about rows but you can just as well put them into columns you create dynamically.

But all this is really only worth it if you hit the **limit** of controls in `Winforms` with a `FLP`.

Well, if `WPF` is an option, there all this will not be an issue..

Comment: Wow, a lot of information here! You've convinced me that a DGV is not necessary for my purposes. I'm going to look into FlowLayoutPanels as well as TableLayoutPanels. I appreciate your time and effort, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me.I can not write English.

But the sample code I wrote may help solve this problem and I am happy if that happens.

[Display user controls in C # 4.0 Winforms DataGridView](http://cscodememo.blogspot.jp/2017/11/c40-winforms-datagridview.html)

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Spell out specific steps and code samples in your answer instead. ;)

Comment: Also, the link is mostly in Japanese.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I will post code samples in the future