# Add Custom Control to DataGridView Cells

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `DataGridView` and I want to add a `Control` on a specific cell. It successfully adds the control to the Grid. My problem is when i reside the Grid, the control stays in its position, not following the column when i want it to show. Also, when i resize the column, the control is not resizing. Any ideas? Below is my code:

`FileBrowser` is a `user control`. Composed of `textbox` and a `button`.

```
int intColIndex = 4;
int intRowIndex = 3;

FileBrowser fileBrowser = new FileBrowser();
dgv.Controls.Add(FileBrowser);
dgv[intColIndex, intRowIndex].Value = dt.Rows[intRowIndex]["Value"].ToString();
fileBrowser.Location = dgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(intColIndex, intRowIndex, true).Location;
fileBrowser.Size = dgv.GetCellDisplayRectangle(intColIndex, intRowIndex, true).Size;
fileBrowser.SelectedFile = dt.Rows[intRowIndex]["Value"].ToString();
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at these posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335494/using-a-custom-usercontrol-as-a-column-in-a-datagridview/36339884?s=1|63.2655#36339884) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005397/accordion-in-windows-forms-datagridview/29006361?s=4|34.0427#29006361)

Comment: Thanks @TaW, I worked on a custom column. It's working okay when I used it as a DatagridviewColumn, but I want to add it as a control in a row like ` DataGridViewTextBoxCell TextBoxCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
 dgv[intColIndex, intRowIndex] = TextBoxCell;
dgv[intColIndex, intRowIndex].Value = dt.Rows[i]["Value"].ToString();`