# Draw panel on datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is the any way to draw a panel above a couple of datagridview rows (see image below)? I need to design a master detail grid. I thought a simple solution for this might be to draw a panel onto the main grid. And then load the second grid in the panel.

[image]

Comment: yes there is a way.. try doing a simple google search - there are lots of hits. here is one if you can understand the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055737/add-a-panel-to-datagridview

Comment: You need a cleare description/understanding of your goal. Do you want the Panel/2nd DGV hosted inside or overlaid? The latter will not scroll with the rows, the former will if you get it right.. DGV is not really good at hosting other controls. See here for an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005397/accordion-in-windows-forms-datagridview/29006361?s=1|2.0756#29006361) of a nestd UserCOntrol but note that the code as is doesn't support scolling..

Comment: I need the second panel, which will contain a grid, to be overlaid.